# appending flash message in json , web2py

Tags: flash, json, append, message, web2py

I am querying web2py using json. I want to append the flash message in the json object that is returned. By default web2py makes json object only of variables used in the page. One way to go about this is manually append flash message in all the dict objects that i return which may not be feasible all the time.

I am using simple dictionary rendered json.

thanks for the response in advance

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

You could use the `generic.json` view to return your JSON, and add code to that view to include the flash message in the returned JSON:

```
{{from gluon.serializers import json}}
{{response._vars.update(flash=response.flash)}}
{{=XML(json(response._vars))}}
```

Note, generic views are now disabled by default, so you'll have to explicitly enable the generic JSON view via `response.generic_patterns=['json']` (ideally, you should only enable the generic view for requests that require it -- if it is available for requests not intended to return JSON, it can be used to expose data returned to the view that was not meant to be exposed). You can also explicitly specify `generic.json` (or any name you would like to give it) via `response.view='generic.json'`.

Comment: Where should we add the statement "response._vars.update(flash=response.flash)" ?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at an old version of generic.json. I updated that answer above. Try putting the above code in /views/generic.json.

Comment: In most of the functions i am returning dict element so adding a flash message as a variable is as good as adding one more element in dictionary say if previously it was `return dict(list=list)`, just change it to `return dict(list=list,flash=response.flash)`

Comment: OK, I thought you were trying to avoid that (though it's probably for the best, as it is more explicit than automatically adding the flash message in the generic view).